# Creating a graph in android studio

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room, dagger-2

I'm trying to create a graph that shows user input against time, which have been submitted in a different page

I've looked at dagger-2 and room, but i can't find any tutorials on how to integrate them into my app in a way i can understand (i'm new to android studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger2 is used for Dependency Injection, so I think it's not directly relate to your problem.
You can save user input in Room database, then use Room to query those data. To show data in a chart view, you can try this [MPChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library, it's quite powerful in terms of creating chart view.